# Grails Project Not Compiling Automatically in STS Version 2.9.2

Tags: java, grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I have a project which has couple of plugins. It has a fairly large amount of classes. The problem is when I tried to save the changes in my code (ie in a controller or gsp file), it doesnt automatically compile. The project by the way is running, but if I change something lets say in the controller or gsp file, it doesnt automatically compile and therefore the changes doesn't take effect. I have to stop the run process first and then run it again so that the changes will take effect. I just encounter this problem recently. I am using SpringSourceToolSuite Version: 2.9.2.RELEASE. I checked the Automatic Build option and it was turned on. Any idea why is this happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Try running grails from command line, in order to figure out whether it is grails or STS specific

Comment: Also, have a look at your STS error log.  Anything interesting?